# jQuery function call not working - Newbie Q

Tags: jquery, html

The idea is to create a square thumbnail defined by whether the height or width is greater. It simply is not doing anything. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Dan

```
function  galDisplay(){
   var galSingleImgH(this).height();
   var galSingleImgW(this).width();
   var galSingleImgWSum(this).width()/2;
   var galSingleImgHSum(this).height()/2;

   if(galSingleImgW > galSingleImgH){
       jQuery(this).attr('style','height:63px;width:auto;margin-left:50%;left:-'+ galSingleImgWSum +'px;');
   } else {
       jQuery(this).attr('style','height:auto;width:63px;margin-top:50%;top:-'+ galSingleImgHSum +'px;');
   }
}

jQuery('.rhsGallery .notFirst a img').galDisplay();
```

Comment: Yes- there are 3 images that it should affect and it's within the (document).ready()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable definitions are wrong, use this instead:

```
var galSingleImgH = jQuery(this).height();
var galSingleImgW = jQuery(this).width();
var galSingleImgWSum = jQuery(this).width()/2;
var galSingleImgHSum = jQuery(this).height()/2;
```

Comment: Well spotted - That fixed it. Thanks Veger!

Answer (score 1):

`galDisplay` is a global, not a method of jQuery objects. See [the jQuery documentation of plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

It looks like changing

```
function  galDisplay(){
```

to

```
jQuery.fn.galDisplay = function (){
```

should do the job.

You will also need to fix your syntax errors.

```
var galSingleImgH(this).height();
```

should be

```
var galSingleImgH = this.height();
```

… and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot some `=`s on the upper 4 lines:
(oh, and wrong way of calling `galDisplay()`)

```
function  galDisplay(){
       var galSingleImgH = (this).height();
       var galSingleImgW = (this).width();
       var galSingleImgWSum = (this).width()/2;
       var galSingleImgHSum = (this).height()/2;

       if(galSingleImgW > galSingleImgH){
           jQuery(this).attr('style','height:63px;width:auto;margin-left:50%;left:-'+ galSingleImgWSum +'px;');
       } else {
           jQuery(this).attr('style','height:auto;width:63px;margin-top:50%;top:-'+ galSingleImgHSum +'px;');
       }
   }

   galDisplay(jQuery('.rhsGallery .notFirst a img'));
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, your code is wrong:

```
var galSingleImgH(this).height();
           var galSingleImgW(this).width();
           var galSingleImgWSum(this).width()/2;
           var galSingleImgHSum(this).height()/2;
```

This won't ever work. I'd advise you to use Developer Tools to see this error in your browser.

It should be:

```
var galSingleImgH = (this).height();
           var galSingleImgW = (this).width();
           var galSingleImgWSu = (this).width()/2;
           var galSingleImgHSum = (this).height()/2;
```

Secondly, if this doesn't correct things, can you include your rhsGallery HTML in your question?